# References for iterative methods for linear systems

Tags: reference-request, optimization, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

I study *[Iterative Methods for Sparse Linear Systems](http://www-users.cs.umn.edu/~saad/IterMethBook_2ndEd.pdf)*, 
and i want know if there exists any books with a clear problem and solution in this topic.

Comment: You should be more specific as to what you need and how skilled you are in mathematics and computer science. One could references you to book's by Iain Duff or Tim Davis, but unless you supply more information it is hard to make a good choice.

Comment: thanks, i'm in first year master degree in maths & applications, I want a books with solved exercises, and problems with solutions, to prepare myself to exams. we use book **Iterative Methods for Sparse Linear Systems** as main reference in course, but i want book like **Exercises in Analysis** (Leszek Gasinski, Nikolaos S. Papageorgiou), that have solved exercises in (basic iterative methods, projection methods, KRYLOV subspace methods)

Comment: IMO Saad's book is the best source for this topic. He has another book "Numerical Methods for Large Eigenvalue Problems" which often contains interesting chapters that are related to this book. If you want exercise material I suggest to search for lectures about this topic. Have a look at the homepages and maybe you find exercises as well.